# RFM анализ. подсчет общего кол-ва пользователей и суммы

Tags: mysql

Как правильно вывести общую сумму по полю `price`  и `count(distinct user_id)` из таблицы

```
SELECT o.user_id, count(id_o), SUM(price), datediff('2018-01-01', DATE_FORMAT(max(o_date),"%Y-%m-%d")) as days, 
CASE WHEN datediff('2018-01-01', DATE_FORMAT(max(o_date),"%Y-%m-%d")) <= 30 THEN "3"
  WHEN datediff('2018-01-01', DATE_FORMAT(max(o_date),"%Y-%m-%d")) BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN "2"
     ELSE "1"
END AS R,
CASE WHEN COUNT(id_o) >= 5 THEN "3"
  WHEN COUNT(id_o) >= 2 AND COUNT(id_o) < 5 THEN "2"
     ELSE "1"
 END AS F,
t.M
FROM shop_1.orders_lessons_1 as o
join
(SELECT user_id,
CASE WHEN sum(price) >= 20000 THEN "3"
  WHEN sum(price) < 20000 and sum(price) >= 10000 THEN "2"
     ELSE "1"
END AS M   
FROM shop_1.orders_lessons_1 group by user_id) as t
on o.user_id = t.user_id
group by user_id
having R != "1" and F != "3" and t.M != "3"
order by user_id;
```

я пыталась сделать таким образом:

```
    SELECT count(distinct user_id), sum(price) 
    from shop_1.orders_lessons_1 as shop
    join
    (табл.выше) as tabl
    on shop.user_id = tabl.user_id
having R != "1" and F != "3" and t.M != "3";
```

но выдает ошибку

```
 50000  Error Code: 1052. Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous   0,035 sec
```

Comment: *Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous* В переводе на русский это означает: "поле `user_id` есть более чем в одной таблице, и я хрен знает, из какой брать, алиас таблицы добавь, да...". И пофиг, что они типа равны по условию связывания - сервер не терпит неопределённостей. PS. И вообще - если в запросе более 1 таблицы, всегда указывайте алиас КАЖДОМУ полю, даже когда поле очевидно уникально именовано, это best practice.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавила алиас, как рекомендовали. Вот полный код, возможно кому-нибудь пригодится

```
SELECT count(distinct shop.user_id), sum(shop.price) 
from shop_1.orders_lessons_1 as shop
join
(SELECT o.user_id, count(id_o), SUM(price), datediff('2018-01-01', DATE_FORMAT(max(o_date),"%Y-%m-%d")) as days, 
CASE WHEN datediff('2018-01-01', DATE_FORMAT(max(o_date),"%Y-%m-%d")) <= 30 THEN "3"
  WHEN datediff('2018-01-01', DATE_FORMAT(max(o_date),"%Y-%m-%d")) BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN "2"
     ELSE "1"
END AS R,
CASE WHEN COUNT(id_o) >= 5 THEN "3"
  WHEN COUNT(id_o) >= 2 AND COUNT(id_o) < 5 THEN "2"
     ELSE "1"
 END AS F,
t.M
FROM shop_1.orders_lessons_1 as o
join
(SELECT user_id,
CASE WHEN sum(price) >= 20000 THEN "3"
  WHEN sum(price) < 20000 and sum(price) >= 10000 THEN "2"
     ELSE "1"
END AS M   
FROM shop_1.orders_lessons_1 group by user_id) as t
on o.user_id = t.user_id
group by user_id
having R = "1") as s
on shop.user_id = s.user_id;
```